# SQL query to copy the column value to another column after checking two conditions

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I have a table customers, in which i have 6 attributes

```
CustomerID  CustomerName CustomerCity CustomerState DuplicateCustIND
1           Richard      Los Angeles  New York 
2           Jerome       Houston      Texas   
3           Paul         Los Angeles  New York
```

In the above table, there are two duplicate column values CustomerCity and CustomerState are same for Richard and Paul. I would like to update the column DuplicateCustIND for paul with the customer id of Richard after checking the two similar column condition.

Till now I was  using correlation query as

```
Update Customer C1 set C1.DuplicateCustIND = (select CustomerID  from customers 
                                             where C3.CustomerCity = 
                                             C1.CustomerCity and
                                             C3.CustomerState = 
                                             C1.CustomerState)
where exists(
Select 1 from Customers C2 where
C2.CustomerCity = C1.CustomerCity and
C2.CustomerState = C1.CustomerState and 
C2.RowID<C1.RowID);
```

The above query didn't help me.

Comment: Surprisingly `mysql <> sql-server`! Did you know that?

Comment: Why is Paul's record being updated instead of Richard's?  Also, what would happen if there were, say, 3 or 4 records which all had the same city and state?  And please tell us which database you are using.

Comment: After you decide which DBMS you are using you need to provide some details. This would be a good place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: I'm not American but isn't Los Angeles in California state and not New York state

Comment: @Cool_Br33ze I _am_ American, have lived in both cities, and no, they're in different states :-)

Comment: i am using oracle DB.

Comment: `C2.CustomerState = C2.CustomerState` will always be true.   Did you make a typo?

Comment: Why is Paul's record being updated instead of Richard's? - this was an example for my real data.... it is my requirement.

Comment: Also, what would happen if there were, say, 3 or 4 records which all had the same city and state? - i just gave a small example of the real data... there are more than a million records to be handled

Comment: Surprisingly mysql <> sql-server! Did you know that? - i was in hurry to post the questions so added the tags from suggestion.... yes i know the difference

Comment: C2.CustomerState = C2.CustomerState will always be true. Did you make a typo? - Yes... it was a typo..

Comment: How do you decide Paul's records should be updated with Richard's and not vice versa?

Comment: Is 6 also a typo? I only see five columns (in a relational database, they are called "columns" rather than "attributes" although the concepts are clearly similar).

Comment: Question: "What should happen if there are three or four customers, all with the same city and state?" Your answer: "My real data has a million rows, I just gave a small example." This proves you didn't understand the question. Please read the question again and answer it properly; it doesn't matter how many rows you have in the input, the question is what to do if four customers (Ada, Ben, Che and Dao) all have the same city and state. Whose row must be updated, and with what value?

Comment: maybe you want this (if CustomerID uniq)?: 1) chane to **min(C3.CustomerID)** 2) add **C3.CustomerID < C1.CustomerID** 3) change C2.RowID<C1.RowID to **C2.CustomerID<C1.CustomerID**

Comment: the question is what to do if four customers (Ada, Ben, Che and Dao) all have the same city and state. - if all have same city and state then i need to update Ben, Che and Dao's column DuplicateCustIND with customerid of Ada.

Comment: Is 6 also a typo? - no sixth column DuplicateCustIND is a column in DB... just i have not given any values in that column

Comment: @Venkata Ramana Murthy - Did you get the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may probably rely on `customerid` and use a `MERGE` statement to update all records greater than that `customerid` with same city and state.

```
MERGE INTO customers t USING
  ( SELECT MIN(c1.CUSTOMERID) prim_id,
           c2.CUSTOMERID sec_id
   FROM Customers c1
   JOIN customers c2 ON C2.CustomerCity = C1.CustomerCity
   AND C2.CustomerState = C1.CustomerState
   AND C2.CustomerID > C1.CustomerID
   GROUP BY C1.CustomerCity,
            C1.CustomerState,
            c2.CUSTOMERID ) s ON (s.sec_id = t.CustomerID ) 
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE
SET t.DuplicateCustIND = s.prim_id;
```

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cccb4d1/1)

Answer (score 1):

The below query could work.

```
merge INTO customers tgt USING
(SELECT   a.id,
    a.cname,
    a.ccity,
    a.cstate
  FROM customers a,
    (SELECT   ccity,
        cstate,
        COUNT(*)
      FROM customers b
      GROUP BY ccity,
        cstate
      HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
    ) b
  WHERE a.ccity  = b.ccity
    AND a.cstate = b.cstate
) src ON (tgt.id = src.id)
WHEN matched THEN
  UPDATE SET tgt.dcustid = src.id;
```